# Handling Empty Sections in Linker Script Causes Hard Fault on STM32H7

Tags: linker, stm32, gnu, linker-scripts

I'm working with an STM32H7 microcontroller and encountered a Hard Fault during the startup sequence while copying data from Flash to RAM (specifically to ITCM and DTCM sections). This issue arises under specific conditions related to the presence (or absence) of data in these memory regions, as well as their ordering in the linker script.

Linker Script Configuration:

My linker script segments are ordered as follows:

```
SECTIONS
{
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH
  
  /* DTCM --------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  
  /* Used by the startup to initialize dtcm */
  _siDTCM = LOADADDR(.dtcm_data);
  
  /* Uninitialized dtcm sections into "DTCM" Ram type memory */
  .dtcm_data :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _sdtcm = .; /* Create a symbol marking the start of the DTCM data */
    *(.dtcm_data)   /* Place the data in the .dtcm section here */
    *(.dtcm_data*)  /* Place the data* in the .dtcm section here */
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _edtcm = .; /* Mark the end of the DTCM data */
  } >DTCMRAM AT> FLASH
  
  /* ITCM --------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    
  /* Used by the startup to initialize data */
  _siITCM = LOADADDR(.itcmram);

  /* Text section into "ITCM" Ram type memory */
  .itcmram :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _sitcm = .;     /* Create a symbol marking the start of the ITCM data */
    *(.itcmFunc)    /* Place the itcmFunc in the .itcm section here */
    *(.itcmFunc*)   /* Place the itcmFunc* in the .itcm section here */
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _eitcm = .; /* Mark the end of the ITCM data */
  } >ITCMRAM AT> FLASH
  
  /* FLASH -------------------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* The program code and other data into "FLASH" Rom type memory */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(8);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data into "FLASH" Rom type memory */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  ...
}
```

Startup Routine:

The startup code copies initialized data from Flash to ITCM and DTCM. It functions correctly when there's data within these sections. However, it leads to a Hard Fault when these sections are empty:

```
/* Copy the data segment initializers from flash to ITCM SRAM */
  ldr r0, =_sitcm
  ldr r1, =_eitcm
  ldr r2, =_siITCM
  movs r3, #0
  movs r4, #0
  b LoopCopyItcmInit

CopyItcmInit:
  ldr r4, [r2, r3]
  str r4, [r0, r3]
  adds r3, r3, #4

LoopCopyItcmInit:
  adds r4, r0, r3
  cmp r4, r1
  bcc CopyItcmInit

/* Copy the data segment initializers from flash to DTCM SRAM */
  ldr r0, =_sdtcm
  ldr r1, =_edtcm
  ldr r2, =_siDTCM
  movs r3, #0
  movs r4, #0
  b LoopCopyDtcmInit

CopyDtcmInit:
  ldr r4, [r2, r3]
  str r4, [r0, r3]
  adds r3, r3, #4

LoopCopyDtcmInit:
  adds r4, r0, r3
  cmp r4, r1
  bcc CopyDtcmInit
```

Observations and Question:

The system does not encounter a Hard Fault when the .dtcm_data and .itcmram sections have data.
A Hard Fault occurs during the "Copy Data Loop" if .dtcm_data and .itcmram are empty.
Rearranging the linker script to place .dtcm_data and .itcmram sections under the .text section resolves the issue, suggesting that the section order might impact the behavior.
My questions are:

- Why does the startup code result in a Hard Fault when attempting to copy from **empty** .dtcm_data and .itcmram sections? How does rearranging these sections to follow the .text section in the linker script prevent the Hard Fault? (Below rearrangement of sections does solve)

```
.isr_vector : { ... } >FLASH

.text : { ... } >FLASH

.dtcm_data : { *(.dtcm_data) *(.dtcm_data*) } >DTCMRAM AT> FLASH

.itcmram : { *(.itcmram) *(.itcmram*) } >ITCMRAM AT> FLASH
...
```

- Does the order of sections in a linker script influence the initialization behavior or memory allocation in a way that's significant here?
- Can anyone explain or provide insights into this behavior?

Comment: I've updated my post to include the complete configurations for the DTCM, ITCM, and text sections.

Comment: can you step through the startup code with a debugger? It could be empty sections affect some load address in memory, so you could see some invalid addresses in symbols defined in linker script? Just a guess, but something I would try

Comment: Sorry for my late reply:

I'm debugging using J-Link via STM32IDE. When performing step-by-step debugging, I'm encountering unexpected behavior in the CopyDtcmInit/LoopCopyDtcmInit loop. Intriguingly, the disassembled code doesn't match my source code, despite compiling with -g3 for maximum debug information.

The execution unexpectedly jumps to a Hard Fault handler at the instruction adds r4, r0, r3. Concurrently, J-Link Ozone warns: "Value may be incorrect: runtime code areas (RAM) not yet initialized." Moreover, the UFSR->INVSTATE Fault register is set.

Comment: From what I see on the internet, this error means you try to use ARM instruction set instead of Thumb instruction set. This happens when you jump to function address, whose least significant bit is not set, or if you initialize the stack and forget to set Thumb instruction set bit in xPSR register on stack (to be loaded into CPU registers), bit 24 of xPSR must be always set, if I remember correctly. Could be something corrupts initial xPSR or jumps to a function with memory address not ending with binary 1.